# Effect of incomplete Disallow rule in robots.txt file

Tags: robots.txt

**Solved: Pages were being blocked by meta robots deliberately**

A lot of pages are being blocked in the robots.txt file and when I checked the file there were no indications of a rule that blocks these.

The robots.txt file is structured:

```
Sitemap: https://domain.com/sitemap.xml
User-agent: *
Disallow: /directory-1/
Disallow: /directory-2/
Disallow: /directory-3/
Disallow: /directory-4/
Disallow: /directory-5/

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:
```

None of the directories in the robots file match the URLs that are being blocked.

I was wondering if the incomplete `Disallow` could be the issue, despite it being only applicable to Googlebot-Image?

Comment: How do you know something is being blocked?

Comment: I found it in a Moz report but, I must have read it wrong as these pages are being blocked in the meta deliberately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found that an incomplete Disallow allows all robots complete access.

Found the answer here: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: "all robots complete access" - well, in your case, it specifically allows the Googlebot-Image robot complete access, not "all robots".